# Why I can't crash the program even though I am following codes from book "Hacking-The art of exploitation"

Tags: c, linux

I am following codes from book "Hacking-The art of exploitation". The source code defined in the book are come along with the CD that the author has provided. I simply compile the pre-written code.According to the book if I provide  right password it should grant me access, and if I give a large string with wrong password it should also grant me access but it is denying me.The source does are as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password) {
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];



strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;

    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_authentication(argv[1])) {
        printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
        printf("      Access Granted.\n");
        printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a larger string than the one you provided?

Comment: Yes I did but it was still denying my access.

Comment: what string are you passing in?

Comment: when I pass "brilling" or "outgrabe" it grant me access. When I pass "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"it denying my access.

Comment: Are you using the virtual machine coming with the book? Some "tricks" depend on the OS architecture, some "tricks" don't work on modern OS having memory and stack protection etc.

Comment: I  already have Orecle VM Virtual box downloaded in my laptop. I am using that not the one come with the CD.

Comment: I have already stop randomization memory process in my VM box in order to make it vulnerable to overflow attack.

Comment: To add to what other commenters have already told you about modern compilers optimizing against stack smashing: we recently tried to demo a version of this (not this thing but stack smashing) and had to use a 10-year-old version of gcc to get the demo to "go off".

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
printf("delta: %td\n", (char *) &auth_flag - password_buffer);
```

in your `check_authentication` function.

If `delta` is negative, your program cannot be exploited.

Otherwise then use an argument of `delta + 4` characters to exploit it.

Comment: Shell I put the prnitf command at the end of Check_authentication function?.Also you have mentioned "delta".Can you explain what does that mean.Sorry I am new to Overflow attacks that is why I did not get some of the words.

Comment: Put it at the beginning. delta here is the distance in bytes in the stack between the beginning of `password_buffer` object and the beginning `auth_flag` object. The `4` is presumably the size of `auth_flag` in your machine

Comment: I have inserted the printf command and compile it.When I enter the right password  it grant me access with delta -4.When I put a long string it still denying me.

Comment: FYI: on my Win7 this example crashed after 28 chars: 16 + 4 + 2*4 with access granted.

Comment: @ZareenaNaz it means it cannot be exploited in your platform. Switch the order of the declarations of `auth_flag` and `password_buffer` variables to exploit it.

Comment: i have inserted "delta +4" in "printf("delta: %td\n",....... "but still it is not granting me access. Anto I have inserted more then 28 chars but still not crashing.

Comment: Ouah I have switched the declaration but still it does not giving me access.I want to do it today to give surprise to my teacher that I have achieved my overflow exploitation code.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested earlier, if there is a particular VM that you can download that is intended to accompany the book you probably want to utilize it. This exploit gives me an error as well rather than the result you'd hope from overflow. E.g. If I try to overflow the buffer using your code on my system, it gives me a *** stack smashing detected *** error. My suspicion is that your OS' Kernel is protecting against this intended exploit.

I'd also suggest you compare the results using the following code instead of strcpy(dest,src):

```
strncpy(password, password_buffer, 16);
```

This has protections against creating a buffer overflow situation. Read the man pages to compare strcpy and strncpy.

Comment: The stack protections usually protect overwriting the saved frame pointer and the return address and not overflowing other variables in the stack. You got the "stack smashing detected" error not because you overwrite `auth_flag` but because you overwrite the sfp / return address.

Comment: tm450 and Ouah Thank you very much for your help.I am going on a business trip to overseas but when I come back I will try the suggestion that you have recommended.

Answer (score 0):

it's a typical buffer overflow attack.

in textbook implementation of c program in linux, temporary variables are stored in stack. in your case, it should be:

```
 -----------------
|int |  char[16] |
 -----------------
                 ^
            stack bottom
```

, address goes down from left to right.

when `strcpy` copy the string to your buffer, it will overflow to int and make it not 0, so it will be true.

but in modern os, this attack may not work. there are some protection mechanisms.

have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection

most likely, modern os's have `canary` implemented so it's not as vulnerable as the book provided.

Comment: Thank you very much HuStmpHm.I am going on a business trip to overseas but when I come back I will look at those websites.